# Can I update the AIR version for Flex Builer 3?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex3, flexbuilder

I am using Flex Builder with Flex SDK 3.2. It has Air 1.0. Now since Air 2 has a whole lot of features that I want to use / study, can I update the AIR version of my Flex Builder so I can build air applications that utilize the new features? I have the 3.5 and 4.0 SKDs with me.

Comment: The air version is updated using the OS updater rather than Flex.You can simply download air2.0 exe from adobes website and start building your apps on for air 2.0

Comment: I have air 2.7 on my system, my question is how to use a later version to develop / build an air app

Comment: get the flex 4.0 sdk downloaded from adobes website, go to the properties tab for flex builder ->Flex Compiler ->Configure Flex SDK -> Add Flex SDK , point it to flex 4 sdk's bin folder and that should be it.

Comment: FlexBuilder 3 gives me error saying abc bytecode decoding failed, also I cannot use any Spark Tags, FB doesnt understand them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tech note from Adobe, http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/495/cpsid_49532.html, will help you overlay any desired version of Adobe AIR SDK on a given Flex SDK. HTH.